# What is the best way to drive 4 relays and 4 MOSFETs (PWM) from an ESP32?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, esp32

I have a project that will require switching of 4 x 5/12 V mini power relays and 4 MOSFETs (switching 12 V load up to 10 A maximum).

I'm quite new to circuit and PCB design and I have been scouring the forums for a solution.

- ESP32 logic 3.3 V
- I have two separate voltages on the board (12-14 V unregulated & 5 V 1 A regulated)
- Open to using either 5 or 12 V coil relays not sure which would work better (considering voltage drop across ULN2004).
- I would ideally like to have the option to PWM the MOSFETs
- All grounds are common
- The MOSFETS will be powering things such as a water pump, LED strips, solenoids

I had originally planned to use a ULN2004 as I thought I could drive the 4 relays and 4 MOSFETs from the same chip (ideal solution) however I now understand that the MOSFETs aren't ideally powered this way and could overrun the 500 mA max on the chip.

There are hundreds of gate drivers and I appreciate there are MOSFETs that can be driven from 3.3 V logic but they seem to all be surface mount and not suitable to carry 10 A with a 3.3 V gate-source.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You could use eight isolated gate drivers (like the [ADuM4120](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM4120-4120-1.pdf)) to drive eight MOSFETs, four of which switch your relays (no preference for the ADuM4120, it was just the first one I thought of).

Comment: @ocrdu i'd ideally like a IC capable of multiple channels to minimise the cost of production.

Comment: Can you post a diagram to show what you are thinking....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need isolation, MOSFETs will be cheaper than relays.

Since your switching frequency will be low, you can either drive the MOSFETs from the ESP32's 3V3 GPIO, or from a 3V3 to 5V level converter. This depends on what MOSFETs you use.

As you say in the question, it may be difficult to find a 10A MOSFET with 3V3 gate drive. In this case, a cheap solution is to use something like 74HCT245 as 8-way translator from 3V3 to 5V, then use 5V gate drive FETs, which should be easier to find.

It doesn't have to be 74HCT245, any logic chip like "octal buffer" or "octal line driver" like HCT240, HCT7541, HCT244, etc, will do the job just fine. In fact any HCT buffer logic chip would work, but if you use an octal buffer, you only need one chip.

It has to be HCT and not HC though. When powered from 5V, HCT chips are compatible with 3V3 logic levels on the input side, but they will output 5V logic levels, which makes them useful for logic level translation.

With the typical 4mA output current of 74HCT, and a MOSFET having 10nC gate charge, it will switch in about 2.5 µs which is not too fast and not too slow.

If you want more output current for faster switching, use 74ACT instead of 74HCT. But slower switching is nice to avoid EMI.

With high current, layout is important: all the high current connectors should be on the same side of the board, with wide copper connections, to make sure the load currents do not travel through the ground plane/tracks along the entire length of the board.

If the power input connector is on one side, and the output connectors are on the other side, then you have to be much more careful about your grounding.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer @bobflux , few follow on questions

The MOSFETs will be a direct solid state replacement for mechanical relays and as such they will not be required to switch any faster than a relay would. 

With regards to the 74HCT245 I'm glad to see I can get it in SMD and THT if required am i able to PWM through the 74HCT245 or is it binary?

Regarding layout i had considered making it a 4 layer board and having a good chunk of an internal layer dedicated to the 12v supply to the FETS, the challenge i have is that I will likely need to switch positive so more components

Comment: It's a logic buffer, so it is binary, but your PWM signal is also binary logic level. It will drive the MOSFET with PWM without trouble. 4 layer should not be necessary if you place the connectors on the same side. High side switching needs more components, but... if you want to use RGB LED strips, all of them are common anode, so the switch has to be low-side, which is more convenient anyway.

Comment: If you want to use high side PMOS instead, you could use an ULN2008 to drive them, with a gate pullup (simpler than 8 transistors).

Comment: The LED strips will likely be single colour, Did you mean ULN2803? i cant find the uln2008 on digikey
I did look at the ULN2008 but thought it was only compatible with relays Would it be possible to use the ULN2008 for example 4 channels for relays 4 channels for PMOS? or would the pullup on gate mess that up?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the part number, I meant ULN2803. It's an open collector darlington, so you can use it for anything, relays, driving MOSFETs with a pull resistor...

Comment: blimy them 2803 is nearly 10 x the price of the 2003, think ill make do with 7!

Comment: Could i use for example a 74hct245 to also switch p mosfets?

Comment: If the PMOS have their sources at 5V then yes. If they're at a higher voltage, since HCT245 can only output 5V, you need a transistor to drive the FET.